# Creating a separate method to read in text files from a subfolder in the assets folder

Tags: java, android, file, methods, assets

This is my first time on here, so I'm bit nervous and please forgive me if I don't seem entirely clear about what I'm asking.

The problem is, Im trying to read in a file from a subfolder in the assets folder, using a method that I've created in a separate class. I've researched this for a couple of days but I'm unable to find the solution anywhere, so I've come here as a last resort. I needed the file reading method to be separate as there are other views/activities that will be utilising exactly the same method and I don't think it would be wise to keep copying and pasting the same code for each activity. Ok here's what I've done so far:

```
public class ReadAssets extends Activity {


public void read(Context context, String filepath, int textviewid) {

    try {
        InputStream input = getAssets().open(filepath);

        int size = input.available();

        // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();

        // Convert the buffer into a string.
        String text = new String(buffer);

        // Finally insert the string into the text view.
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(textviewid);
        tv.setText(text);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Throws an exception if an error is found
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }


  }
}
```

The activity that I would like to place this method in:

```
public class GeneralSetupActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gettingstarted_layout);


    ReadAssets nA = new ReadAssets();
    nA.read(this,"gettingstarted/GettingStarted.txt", R.id.displayTextView);

//  try {
//  InputStream input =getAssets().open("gettingstarted/GettingStarted.txt");
//
//  int size = input.available();
//
//  // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
//  byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
//  input.read(buffer);
//  input.close();
//
// // Convert the buffer into a string.
// String text = new String(buffer);
//
//          // Finally insert the string into the text view.
//          TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayTextView); 
//          tv.setText(text);
//          
//      } catch (IOException e) {
//          // Throws an exception if an error is found
//          throw new RuntimeException(e);
//      }
      }

}
```

I'd really appreciate it file someone could point me towards the right direction. And also I hope I'm not taking advantage but I'd like to know how I'd import and display a series of text files, one after another.

Cheers Guys, 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this available to all different types of Activity, you should consider putting the method in a superclass so all the children can use it.

```
public class ExtraFunctionalActivity extends Activity
{
    public void read(...)
    {        
        //your code
    }
}

public class GeneralSetupUtility extends ExtraFunctionalActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gettingstarted_layout);

        read(this,"gettingstarted/GettingStarted.txt", R.id.displayTextView);

    }
}
```

Otherwise, if this method is needed by a bunch of unrelated classes, you could put it in a utility class;

```
public class FileUtil
{

    public static void read(...)
    {
        //your code
    }

}
```

then you can call it where needed with

```
FileUtil.read(args here);
```

Comment: Thank you.. I created a super class as you said. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You may have a class like Fileparsingutility with the method you want to separate. You may define Inputstream as parameter(you may pass other required things as parameter for that method).  What ever actvity you want to use this method, instantiate above class and invoke the method by passing parameters.

Fileparinsgutility util=new Fileparsingutility();
Returnobj retObj =util.parse(......);